# Use validation on GridView with BoundField

Tags: css, asp.net, if-statement, aspxgridview

I'm new in aspx and I have a grid like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdViewTareas" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="Grid">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="stardate" HeaderText="Fecha Inicio" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="duedate" HeaderText="Fecha Fin" DataFormatString="{0:d}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="progress" HeaderText="% de Avance" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to do a validation for each row of grid to paint background of column for example:

```
if (progress < 100){
background-color: red;
}
```

How can I achieve this. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `OnRowDataBound` event for that.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        DateTime _currentDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime _dueDate = new DateTime();

        //first, check if the date fields are null or empty and then try to convert
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["currentDate"].ToString()))
        {
            _currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["currentDate"]);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["dueDate"].ToString()))
        {
            _dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["dueDate"]);
        }

        //check the value of progress and set the background color
        if (Convert.ToInt32(row["progress"]) < 100 && _currentDate > _dueDate)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"` to the GridView.

If you bound a List of classes `List<Myclass>` you do this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //if you bound a list of classes to the GridView, cast back to the orignal class
        MyClass item = e.Row.DataItem as MyClass;

        //check the propertyu value of the class and set the background color
        if (item.progress < 100 && item.currentDate > item.dueDate)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and if I want to add `and` conditional I just use like if `(Convert.ToInt32(row["progress"]) < 100 && row["stardate"] > row["duedate"])`  or I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, but you need to convert to DateTime `Convert.ToDateTime(row["duedate"])`

Comment: Can you check my edit of your answer please? If I just use validation of "progress" it works: `if (progress < 100 )` but if I add Date validation like `(progress < 100 && currentDate > dueDate)` it throws error

Comment: Is there a possibility that currentDate or duedate can be empty or null?

Comment: Yes they can come null, but I get error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: current date and due date  are  datetime values